# filtrados: saldosDeMesesConGanancia

Tags: javascript, array

tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Ana nos dejó con un problema más interesante: quiere saber los saldos de los meses que hubo ganancia .

```
 saldosDeMesesConGanancia([100, 20, 0, -10, 10])
[100, 20, 10]
```

Completa la función saldos De Meses Con Ganancia. Esta función tiene que devolver un array.

Yo estuve haciendo esto:

```
function saldosDeMesesConGanancia(unPeriodo) {

  var saldos = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < unPeriodo.length;i++) {

    if (unPeriodo[i] <= 0){

      saldos.push([unPeriodo])
    }    
  }
  
}
```

//

Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, qué problema tienes? ¿Qué buscas hacer, que resultado esperas?. Te invito a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), saludos!

Answer (score 0):

coincido con los compañeros en que tu pregunta realmente no esta bien formulada, pero por lo que entendí quieres arreglar tu código y esperas que la respuesta sea:

> [100, 20, 10]

pues tu código quedaría así:

```
function saldosDeMesesConGanancia(unPeriodo) {
  var saldos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < unPeriodo.length; i++) {
    if (unPeriodo[i] > 0){
      saldos.push(unPeriodo[i])
    }    
  }
  return saldos
}
```

Ahora te tengo otra solución un poco mas elegante :)

```
function saldosDeMesesConGanancia2(unPeriodo) {
  return unPeriodo.filter(saldo => saldo > 0);
}
```

toma en cuenta que para ambos casos estamos asumiendo que el parámetro de entrada es un arreglo de números, puede que tengas que hacer las respectivas validaciones si quieres tener un código mas seguro

Espero sea de utilidad :)

Comment: vale, entiendo @BetaM lo tendré en cuenta, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Corrigiendo tu código queda ok

```
function saldosDeMesesConGanancia(unPeriodo) {
  let saldos = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < unPeriodo.length;i++) {
    if (unPeriodo[i] > 0){
      saldos.push(unPeriodo[i])
    }    
  }
  return saldos  
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la corrección? Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.